# Mapper Parsing exception Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters

Tags: search, elasticsearch

I am trying to create an index with autocomplete support successfully but I am unable to add data into it.
Please help me on this, I stuck on this error from last 48hrs.

Please look at the attachment for the settings

PUT http://localhost:9200/my_index/_mapping/users/
Input:

```
{
  "userId": "2",
  "userFirstName": "m4",
  "userLastName": "m4",
  "userMobile": "4047534441",
  "userEmail": "test@gmail.com",
  "userSpecialization": "1:3",
  "userCityId": "6",
  "userCityName":"Hyderabad"
}
```

Outout:

```
{ "error": { "root_cause": [ { "type": "mapper_parsing_exception", "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters: [userId : 2] [userFirstName : m4] [userLastName : m4] [userMobile : 40475341] [userEmail : test@gmail.com] [userSpecialization : 1:3] [userCityId : 6] [userCityName : Hyderabad]" } ], "type": "mapper_parsing_exception", "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters: [userId : 2] [userFirstName : m4] [userLastName : m4] [userMobile : 40475341] [userEmail : test@gmail.com] [userSpecialization : 1:3] [userCityId : 6] [userCityName : Hyderabad]" }, "status": 400 }
```

Settings:

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "aliases": {

    },
    "mappings": {
      "practices": {
        "_all": {
          "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
        },
        "properties": {
          "practiceCity": {
            "type": "string",
            "index":"analyzed"
          },
          "practiceId": {
            "type": "long",
            "index":"not_analyzed"
          },
          "practiceName": {
            "type": "string",
            "boost": 10,
            "index":"analyzed"
          },
          "practicePhone": {
            "type": "long",
            "boost": 10,
            "index":"analyzed"
          },
          "practiceService": {
            "type": "string",
            "boost": 5,
            "index":"not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      },
      "users": {
        "_all": {
          "analyzer": "nGram_analyzer",
          "search_analyzer": "whitespace_analyzer"
        },
        "properties": {
          "userCityId": {
            "type": "long",
            "index":"not_analyzed"
          },
          "userCityName": {
            "type": "string",
            "index":"not_analyzed"
          },
          "userEmail": {
            "type": "string",
            "index":"analyzed"
          },
          "userFirstName": {
            "type": "string",
            "boost": 10,
            "index":"analyzed"
          },
          "userId": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "userLastName": {
            "type": "string",
            "boost": 10,
            "index":"not_analyzed"
          },
          "userMobile": {
            "type": "string",
            "index":"analyzed"
          },
          "userSpecialization": {
            "type": "string",
            "boost": 5,
            "index":"not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "nGram_filter": {
              "max_gram": "20",
              "type": "nGram",
              "min_gram": "3",
              "token_chars": [
                "letter",
                "digit",
                "punctuation",
                "symbol"
              ]
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "nGram_analyzer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding",
                "nGram_filter"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "whitespace"
            },
            "whitespace_analyzer": {
              "type": "custom",
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding"
              ],
              "tokenizer": "whitespace"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "number_of_shards": "5"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you're using to index a new document is wrong. The `_mapping` endpoint is for managing the mapping type not for indexing documents.

Use this one instead and it's going to work.

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/my_index/users/2
{
  "userId": "2",
  "userFirstName": "m4",
  "userLastName": "m4",
  "userMobile": "4047534441",
  "userEmail": "test@gmail.com",
  "userSpecialization": "1:3",
  "userCityId": "6",
  "userCityName":"Hyderabad"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, Yes I was thinking the same, I tried that URL pattern too but it was throwing the following error.

PUT http://localhost:9200/my_index/users
No handler found for uri [/gotomedic/users/] and method [PUT]

after debugging I came to know it is expecting an url
http://localhost:9200/my_index/users/<elastic_document_id>, so at the time of I won't have elastic_document_id because I am not storing that in my DB.

if I use Post the request gets the response successfully but ends up with another duplicate record.

Comment: Yes, with PUT you need to provide an ID, otherwise you can use POST an the id will be auto-generated for you. You can use the `userId` field as an id, it's probably unique, right? `PUT http://localhost:9200/my_index/users/2`

Comment: no it won't identify the record but I tried in the following way.
PUT http://localhost:9200/gotomedic/users/_search?q=userId:8 but it is creating a new duplicate record.

The way you suggested one 
PUT http://localhost:9200/my_index/users/2 only works at the time of elastic_document_id=user_id, I don't know how to make that, I am searching for it, if you know the solution to make some changes to my config please suggest me.

Comment: You cannot PUT on the `_search` endpoint, it doesn't make sense. `_search` is for searching not for indexing. I don't know what you're doing exactly, but it's either `POST /my_index/users` or `PUT /my_index/users/<userId>`

Comment: I understood now Val what you are saying... Thanks a lot, you really saved me. It is working perfectly how I am expecting.